# ios simulator doesn't start black screen invalid device state

Tags: ios, xcode

ios simulator doesn't start - black screen,
xcode display 'invalid device state' when running the simulator

also happens when simulator starts from Spotlight

tried:

- restart mac/xcode/simulator
- reset content and settings

> ```
>  $ xcrun simctl list
>     == Device Types ==
>     iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s)
>     iPhone 5 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5)
>     iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s)
>     iPhone 6 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus)
>     iPhone 6 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6)
>     iPad 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2)
>     iPad Retina (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina)
>     iPad Air (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air)
>     Resizable iPhone (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone)
>     Resizable iPad (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad)
>     == Runtimes ==
>     iOS 8.3 (8.3 - 12F69) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-3)
>     == Devices ==
>     -- iOS 8.3 --
>         iPhone 4s (6EFCAF10-4208-4A5E-B956-500AC64E4F78) (Booted)
>         iPhone 5 (3111A1E3-1950-44CF-9E77-5862AF8D3C0A) (Shutdown)
>         iPhone 5s (C8D57731-039E-41DE-8097-A8AF7A4B8778) (Shutdown)
>         iPhone 6 Plus (42B3FFAB-6718-44E4-9374-9C6A91D91AC2) (Shutdown)
>         iPhone 6 (765AD568-D63E-41F2-822E-6A7DF22E5F61) (Shutdown)
>         iPad 2 (28339A10-7624-46AA-9659-F563F9D70958) (Shutdown)
>         iPad Retina (226EB488-0ECC-4166-BAB5-E787C2EC23B4) (Shutdown)
>         iPad Air (EE9742AC-FFE4-43E3-B7A7-FCFB5E60137D) (Shutdown)
>         Resizable iPhone (6A94AFC8-C862-4984-94B5-E13FCADBA9DC) (Shutdown)
>         Resizable iPad (59E84767-46C5-4A4C-A9D5-E2C4B0600FC2) (Shutdown)
> ```

device stuck in booted state

tried

> xcrun simctl erase all

version: mac 10.10.3, xcode 6.3.2, simulator 8.3

additional info: yesterday before I finished work it was working with no problems, no change made to anything - just tried to run it from skretch this morning.

Trying to upgrade xcode - it is stuck on waiting for 1 day now...

Every day brings a new Xcode issue, is this one solvable? except for throwing another 2000 euro on a new mac

Edit:
Upgrade solved this issue - but just for a few days, no it's back to black.

new version is Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Notes about upgrade:

- upgrade from App Store -> purchased tab
- don't try to pause the upgrade, if you do and the process stuck on waiting see this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152934/os-x-yosemite-xcode-update-stuck-on-waiting
- download can take about 10-20 hours

Comment: Try cleaning derived data folder.

Comment: what is derived data folder?

Comment: Go to XCode->Preferences->Locations->Derived Data

Comment: Didn't help :( the point is that the simulator doesn't start also when not running xcode, so I doubt if any xcode solution will do